# How to select the same option that was chosen in another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-variables

I have a few DropDownList in my homepage:

```
<asp:DropDownList style="width: 245px;" class="default" ID="slcLocation" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
</asp:DropDownList>
<br /><br />
<asp:DropDownList style="width: 245px;" class="default" ID="slcSpecialty" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
</asp:DropDownList>
<br /><br />
<asp:DropDownList style="width: 245px;" class="default" ID="slcGender" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Any Gender" Value="" Selected="True" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Male" Value="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Female" Value="2" />
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Button ID="btnGoAll" class="loginButton" style="padding: 10px; float: right;" Text="Search All" OnClick="btnGoAll_Click" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

First two are auto-populated from code behind, while the last one is populated in my aspx page. When the page is generated the source code looks like this:

```
<select name="ctl00$FeaturedContent$slcLocation" id="slcLocation" class="default" style="width: 245px;">
    <option value="">All Locations</option>
    <option value="89">Theall Road</option>
    <option value="2535">Mamaroneck Avenue</option>
    <option value="1947">Huguenot Street</option>
    <option value="2666">Huguenot Street(1)</option>
    <option value="2435">verhill Road</option>
    <option value="87">estchester Avenue</option>
    <option value="1121">estchester Avenue</option>
    <option value="90">estchester Avenue</option>
    <option value="100">avis Avenue</option>
    <option value="93">te Plains Road Suite 270</option>
    <option value="1532">ic Surgery at WESTMED</option>
    <option value="1606">l, 73 Market Street</option>
    <option value="1241">nter at WESTMED</option>

</select>
<br /><br />
<select name="ctl00$FeaturedContent$slcSpecialty" id="slcSpecialty" class="default" style="width: 245px;">
    <option value="">All Specialties</option>
    <option value="553">Allergy and Immunology</option>
    <option value="315">Anesthesiology</option>
    <option value="140">Breast Surgery</option>
    <option value="141">Cardiology</option>
    <option value="2672">Care Management</option>
    <option value="2509">Chiropractic Medicine</option>
    <option value="688">Clinical Laboratory</option>
    <option value="337">Colon and Rectal Surgery</option>
    <option value="145">Critical Care</option>
    <option value="143">Dermatology / Cosmetic</option>
    <option value="633">Diabetes Education</option>
    <option value="144">Ear, Nose and Throat</option>
    <option value="146">Endocrinology</option>
    <option value="165">Eye Care</option>
    <option value="155">Family Medicine</option>
    <option value="156">Gastroenterology</option>
    <option value="157">General Surgery</option>
    <option value="158">Geriatric Medicine</option>
    <option value="1841">Gynecologic Oncology</option>
    <option value="2345">Hand Surgery</option>
    <option value="159">Hematology and Oncology</option>
    <option value="722">Hospitalist</option>
    <option value="160">Infectious Diseases</option>
    <option value="161">Internal Medicine</option>
    <option value="2069">Interventional Radiology</option>
    <option value="2318">Maternal Fetal Medicine</option>
    <option value="2654">Medical Oncology</option>
    <option value="2309">Mohs Surgery</option>
    <option value="162">Nephrology</option>
    <option value="163">Neurology</option>
    <option value="652">Nutrition</option>
    <option value="164">Obstetrics and Gynecology</option>
    <option value="634">Optical Shop</option>
    <option value="166">Orthopedic Surgery</option>
    <option value="1951">Palliative Medicine</option>
    <option value="1589">Pathology</option>
    <option value="167">Pediatrics and Adolescent Medicine</option>
    <option value="168">Physical Medicine and Rehabilitation</option>
    <option value="169">Plastic Surgery</option>
    <option value="170">Podiatry</option>
    <option value="171">Pulmonology</option>
    <option value="2061">QCOI</option>
    <option value="1460">Radiation Oncology</option>
    <option value="691">Radiology</option>
    <option value="172">Rheumatology</option>
    <option value="2520">Sleep Center</option>
    <option value="2145">Thoracic Surgery</option>
    <option value="951">Urgent Care</option>
    <option value="173">Urology</option>
    <option value="456">Vascular Surgery</option>
    <option value="174">Weight Management</option>

</select>
<br /><br />
<select name="ctl00$FeaturedContent$slcGender" id="slcGender" class="default" style="width: 245px;">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Any Gender</option>
    <option value="1">Male</option>
    <option value="2">Female</option>

</select>
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$FeaturedContent$btnGoAll" value="Search All" id="btnGoAll" class="loginButton" style="padding: 10px; float: right;" />
```

I have a button click option in my homepage like this which saves the variable in a session:

```
protected void btnGoAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var locText = slcLocation.SelectedItem.Text;
        var speText = slcLocation.SelectedItem.Text;
        var genText = slcGender.SelectedItem.Text;

        Session["LocationText"] = locText;
        Session["SpecialtyText"] = speText;
        Session["GenderText"] = genText;

        Response.Redirect("~/physicians.aspx", false);
    }
```

I have the same ASPX code in another page (physician.aspx) which displays the same dropdownlist. What I am looking to is when the user clicks the submit button from the homepage the dropdownlist will auto populate those selections in the `physician.aspx` page.

I have something like this in the `physician.asp` page:

```
public partial class physicians : System.Web.UI.Page {
    string cString = "";
    SqlConnection Conn;
    string strQueryAll = "*";
    string sqlCode = "";
    string theLocation = "", theSpecialty = "", theGender = "";
    string locVal = "", speVal = "", genVal = "";
    string lVal = "", sVal = "", gVal = "";
    int rowCount = 0;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
            PopulatePhysician();
            ASPopulateLocation();
            ASPopulateSpecialty();
        }

        if (Session["LocationText"] != null && Session["SpecialtyText"] != null && Session["GenderText"] != null) {
            //dlo.InnerHtml = "Successfully retrieved " + (string)Session["LocationText"];
            //btnGoAll_OnClick(null, null);
        }
    }
}
```

I also have a button in the `physician.aspx` page which I would like to auto-click so it's as if the user clicked on the physician page.

I just need some help in figured out how to achieve the session transfer and auto-populating. Should I take the text or the value in the session and how would I apply it to the `physician.aspx` page?

I am thinking I need a function that executes **after** the page loads, as the control has not been initialized yet?

Can I use Javascript to achieve the function? How would I make it work with the session i am receiving through C#?

Comment: Instead of creating 3 session variables create a custom entity and set values (not text as its not a good coding practice) in them and set it in a single session, also check for session within the !isPostBack else u will end up setting the same values again no matter what the user selects

Comment: Thank you for the response. I can use `.Value` instead of `.Text` in the homepage and then how would I set it in the physician page? I am new to ASP.net development so I would request all the help I can get. :)

Comment: you can do it on server side (c#) using slcLocation.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(Session["LocationText"]);

Comment: With your code it looks like I have to use `.Value` instead of `.Text` in the homepage code-behind? Or I can do `slcLocation.SelectedItem` in the physician page?

Comment: I changed the homepage code to this: `var locText = slcLocation.SelectedItem.Value; Session["LocationText"] = locText;` and in my physician page I did this: `slcLocation.SelectedValue = Convert.ToInt32(Session["LocationText"]);`. I get this error: `CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'`

Comment: it is .ToString() not to Convert.ToInt32.

Comment: You beat me to it. I am testing it now. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know why only the first session works? The other variables are not working :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53973/discussion-between-karthik-ganesan-and-searchforknowledge).

Comment: Session is likely not a good choice to use for interpage communication like that. If the user has multiple tabs/windows open on your site, the user may end up with unexpected values. Try looking into using QueryString instead of Session.

Comment: Hmmmmmmmm What if I give them unique ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have a common function like

```
public void OnBtnClick()
{
 // add the code with the query to database
}
```

and on page load you can call the function like this

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
            PopulatePhysician();
            ASPopulateLocation();
            ASPopulateSpecialty();
        }

        if (Session["LocationText"] != null && Session["SpecialtyText"] != null && Session["GenderText"] != null) {

            this.OnBtnClick();
        }
    }
```

and on button click event handler just call the common function again

```
protected void btnGoAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
this.OnBtnClick();
}
```